# MessagePack and Glassfish

Tags: exception, glassfish, classpath, messagepack

I'm trying to use MessagePack in a WAR application in Glassfish, but I'm getting this exception (although JavaAssist already is a library of the project):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/ClassPath   at
>   org.msgpack.template.builder.BuilderSelectorRegistry.initForJava(BuilderSelectorRegistry.java:58)
>     at
>   org.msgpack.template.builder.BuilderSelectorRegistry.(BuilderSelectorRegistry.java:38)
>     at
>   org.msgpack.template.TemplateRegistry.(TemplateRegistry.java:38)
>     at org.msgpack.MessagePack.register(MessagePack.java:149)

this happern When I call

> `org.msgpack.MessagePack.register()`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the error in the [MessagePack's JIRA](http://jira.msgpack.org/browse/MSGPACK-32) and this is the answer:

> I added this libraries to my classpath:
>
> javassist.jar msgpack-0.5.2-devel.jar slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
>   slf4j-ext-1.6.2.jar slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar
>
> Copying them directly to the lib folder of glassfish, to: C:\Program
>   Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
>
> I'm gonna work now in adding them as part of my war
>
> Thank you very much again.